# Domain, SSL Certificate and Webhost in from different providing companies

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, https

I am planning to migrate from godaddy to another webhosting company but not including my domain registrations. I have two domain names and I am planning to get one free domain name from the webhosting company that I will be relocated.

**My Questions**

1) if the domain registration and the webhost is in a different hosting company how thus it affects the speed of my site, how long my domains will be resolved so that my customers will reach my web host?

2) I am planning to get a multi domain SSL certificate for my two domains, how will the two different providers will affect my ssl certificate installation?.

Note: I will have a dedicated Ip to my new webhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) if the domain registration and the webhost is in a different
>   hosting company how thus it affects the speed of my site, how long my
>   domains will be resolved so that my customers will reach my web host?
>
> 2) I am planning to get a multi domain SSL certificate for my two
>   domains, how will the two different providers will affect my ssl
>   certificate installation?.

Having a separate host, registrar, and SSL provider is common and normal. Doing this will not affect your website's speed or performance in any way.

Typically when you change web hosts it takes just a few hours for the domain to propagate. But it can take up to a full day in some circumstances. But if you start off with your domain pointing to your separate web host it should resolve immediately.